# How to run c++ programs on new terminal window after compilation in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Once I compile and run the code in currently opened vim, the window shifts to terminal where I can input the data. I want the code to run on a separate window, so that I can look at my code too at the same time.
SublimeText is a good example, where I can choose which terminal emulator to run my code on. And, the code runs on a separate window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your program in vim integrated window terminals with:

```
:term ./%<
" or
:vert term ./%<
```

(I've used `./%<` to designate `foo` in the current directory supposing your edited file is `foo.cpp` that you've compiled into `foo`).

If you prefer you could use instead another windowed terminal by using `:!xterm`, `:!gterm` or whatever. Don't forget the argument that tells what to run in the terminal. Sometimes it changes from one to the other.